# Webkit Mutation Observer callback not triggered when select box attribute's change

Tags: javascript, forms, mutation-observers

I am trying to monitor changes to select box (or nested `option` elements) with new [Mutation Observer](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) functionality. However, only "setAttribute" is triggering mutation observer's callback for me.

Here's the code I am using:

```
~function(doc, $) {
    var select = $('select');

    // http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers
    var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        alert(mutations.length + " mutations happened");
    });

    observer.observe(select, {
        // monitor descendant elements – changing `selected` attr on options
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true
    });

    // this triggers Observer's reaction, but doesn't update select box UI
    select.setAttribute('value', 'whee'); 
    // this updates select box UI, but doesn't trigger mutation observer's callback
    select.value = "whee";
    // this also updates the UI, but doesn't trigger mutation observer's callback
    select.getElementsByTagName('option')[0].selected = true;
    //
    // neither does manual selecting of options trigger mutation observer unfortunately :(

    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // my goal is to react to this change here 
        select.value = Math.random() > .5 ? "whee" : "whoa";
    }, false);

}(document, function(selector) { return document.querySelector(selector); });​
```

And here's this code in action http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/wqHn5/

I would like to react to changes to attributes (`selected` on `<option>` or `value` on `<select>`), any suggestion on why observer doesn't react is more than welcome!

I am testing this in Chrome 18.0.1025.168 on Mac OS X. Production code would of course also have a `moz` prefix for the constructor and unprefixed version too, this is testing code.

**UPD.**

Tested the code in Firefox Nightly too and it behaves the same way as in Chrome, as well as in Chrome Canary. I have filled the bug for both browsers:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757077
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128991

Please comment and vote for these bugs if you also find this problem annoying.

Comment: Don't think I'd want to rely on an experimental implementation of an unfinished spec.

Comment: Seems to be another manifestation of a related WebKit-rooted bug reported against Chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103551

Comment: @TimDown who said I am relying on anything? :-) I am experimenting myself!

Comment: perhaps I should report a bug on chrome bug tracker.

Comment: Done: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128991, also filling one for Firefox, as Firefox Nightly has exactly the same behaviour

Comment: While we are waiting for the specs to change, I have devised a terrible ill-conceived library to address this pressing issue: https://github.com/anonyco/IDL-Property-Observer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@gryzzly, I've updated the Chromium bug with a detailed response: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128991#c4

> Mutation Observers are limited to observing the DOM serialized state.
>   If you'd like to know if Mutation Observers can observe something,
>   just do take a look at what innerHTML outputs for the element. If you
>   can see the change in state reflected in changes to the markup which
>   that produces, then Mutation Observers should be able to hear about
>   it.

TL;DR: this is working as intended; to observe changes to IDL attributes like HTMLSelectElement.value, input events like onclick or onchange are probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have written a comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128991#c5

Comment: @gryzzly: adamk's comment on the bug is spot on. Fortunately, for cases where changes to properties such as `value` of form elements are not reflected in DOM attributes, there are alternative events, such as the `change` and `input` events.

Comment: @TimDown as I've written on the issues' pages, the problem is that when JS is changing value like this `select.value = "foo";`, UI updates and when form is submitted the value is the new one, but `change` and `input` events don't fire.

Comment: @gryzzly: Good point. Sorry, I completely failed to read properly.