# How do I check if I have selected the same drop-down list option twice in a row?

Tags: javascript, select-options

Let's supose I have a simple drop-down list from which I can freely select any option I want.

I can, via JavaScript, store the selected option's value in a variable this way:

```js
var checkValue = function(){
  const mySelect = document.getElementById("cars");
  let currentValue =  mySelect.options[ mySelect.selectedIndex ].value;
  console.log(currentValue);
}
```

```html
<select id="cars" onchange="checkValue()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I check if I have selected the same drop-down list option
   twice in a row, in other words, if the value of `currentValue` has
   *changed*?
2. Would using AngularJS make this task easier? How?

Comment: You can not select the same option twice in a row. Ex. if you select `Saab`, then next time you have to unselect it by selecting some other value like `Opel`, and then only you can select `Saab` again.. so, console log will look like `Saab`, `Opel`,  `Saab`

Comment: the value of `currentValue` will always change, because of the select, if you click on the same option it will not trigger the `onChange` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];
var checkValue = function() {
  const mySelect = document.getElementById("cars");
  let currentValue = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value;

  if ($.inArray(currentValue, arr) != "-1") {
    console.log("already selected");
  } else {
    arr.push(currentValue);
    console.log(currentValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="cars" onchange="checkValue()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My question specifies "twice *in a row*". In other words, if you select an option that is *already* selected.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for onclick event and then check whether the value is the same:

```js
var checkValue = function(){
  let mySelect = document.getElementById("cars").options;
  let currentValue =  mySelect[ mySelect.selectedIndex ].value;
  if (currentValue === previousValue) {
    console.log("The same option was selected");
  } else {
    console.log("Different option");
  }
  previousValue = currentValue;
}

let select = document.getElementById("cars").options;
let previousValue = select[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo" onclick="checkValue(this)">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" onclick="checkValue(this)">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" onclick="checkValue(this)">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" onclick="checkValue(this)">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you console.log "The same option was selected" if the same drop-down list option is selected twice in a row?

Comment: Check my last update, it logs when it's the same value or not. It logs whether the option is selected twice in a row (Same value) or not (Different value).

Answer (score 0):

An example of triggering event on element select twice in a row might be to add click event instead of change event, I was thinking about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but it seems this one doesn't trigger when listening to options change if its already selected check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411824/webkit-mutation-observer-callback-not-triggered-when-select-box-attributes-chan)

```js
var activities = document.getElementById("activitySelector");

activities.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('selected item');
});
```

```html
<select id="activitySelector">
  <option value="addNew">Item</option>
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
</select>
```

with click event you can do this:

```js
let selectedoptions = [];
var clickListener = function(){
  const mySelect = document.getElementById("cars");
  let currentValue =  mySelect.options[ mySelect.selectedIndex ].value;
  if(selectedoptions.indexOf(currentValue) < 0) {
    selectedoptions.push(currentValue);
  }
  else {
    console.log('selected before');
  }
  //console.log(currentValue);
}
```

```html
<select id="cars" onclick="clickListener()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```